# Whether mongodb can be used to save this format of document or something else?

Tags: mongodb, database

I am asking a question about whether mongodb can be used for below data format.

```
**Header**
GSGT Version    1.9.4
Processing Date 12/28/2016 4:07 PM
Content         GSAMD-24v1-0_20011747_A1.bpm
Num SNPs        700078
Total SNPs      700078
Num Samples     44
Total Samples   48
File    1 of 44
**Data**
Sample ID       SNP Name        Allele1 - Plus  Allele2 - Plus  Allele1 - AB    Allele2 - AB
B01     1:100292476     A       A       A       A
B01     1:101064936     A       A       A       A
B01     1:103380393     G       G       B       B
B01     1:104303716     G       G       B       B
B01     1:104864464     C       C       B       B
B01     1:106737318     T       T       A       A
B01     1:109439680     A       A       A       A
...
```

The above data is one data record and I am going to have millions of such records. I want to find a good database for storing this kind of data. And `MongoDB` is the one I want to use. One such record can be saved as one document. The whole data will be saved into a collection. Below is a description of the data structure.

One record includes `header` and `data` two parts. The `data` parts usually have 700,000 lines. In order to save them into `MongoDB` I propose to change the format into json as a collection as below:

```
{ "header":{
     "GSGT Version": "1.9.4",
     "Processing Date" : "12/28/2016 4:07 PM",
     ...
   },
   "data" : [{
      "Sample ID": "B01",
      "SNP Name": "1:100292476",
      "Allele1 - Plus" : "A",
       ...
     },{
       "Sample ID": "B01",
      "SNP Name": "1:100292476",
      "Allele1 - Plus" : "A",
      ...
     }
   ...
   }
```

Since the data part has 700,000 lines I am not confident about this design. What is the reasonable number of nested data in one document? If I save such record in one document whether it is good for querying, saving? Or should I split this data into two collections? Or are there any other databases better than MongoDB to handle this structure?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can.

Mongo Supports **rich data**.

Also you can index them for faster retrieval and embed them to query specifically

But you have to make sure that your individual document (record) doesn't grow more than **16 megabytes**